# UWP C++ App Passing OpenCV related Class between Pages

Tags: visual-studio, windows-runtime, uwp, c++-cx

actually I'm writing a C++/CX App for the Universal Windows Platform. I'm trying to pass a class with different Variables that are not part of the Windows Runtime (like cv::detail::WaveCorrectKind and std::string) from one Page-Element to another. Directly passing it in the Navigate-method like an object is not possible. Writing it in an external class and make it accessable for other Page-Elements is also not possible cause it is giving me some Errors whenever I try to use some nonWinRT Variables or Classes in the public section for access from other Page Elements. Here is an example code of what I would like to have.

The Header of the Page1:

```
//Page1.h
// Deklaration der Page1-Klasse

#pragma once

#include "Page1.g.h"
#include "Bibliothek.h"

namespace eigeneApp
{
    [Windows::Foundation::Metadata::WebHostHidden]
    public ref class Page1 sealed
    {
    public:
        Page1();

    protected:
        //Navigations Events
        virtual void OnNavigatedTo(Windows::UI::Xaml::Navigation::NavigationEventArgs^ e) override;
        virtual void OnNavigatingFrom(Windows::UI::Xaml::Navigation::NavigatingCancelEventArgs^ e) override;    

    private:
        //Buttons Begin
        void toPage2Button_Click(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e);
        //some other Buttonevents for capturing Photos and back to mainpage
        //Buttons Ende
        //A OpenCV related Element out of the Bibliothek.h
        bibitem bibitemElement;

        //Tasks that handle some stuff out of Bibliothek.h (photo processing) and capturing the photos asynchronous 
        // String Helper for Converting Platform::String to std::string and back    
    };
}
```

The cpp-file of Page1:

```
//
// Page1.xaml.cpp
// Implementing Page1-Klasse
//

#include "pch.h"

#include "Page1.xaml.h"
#include "Page2.xaml.h"
//other includes for asynch programming, Strings and so on...
#include "Bibliothek.h"
#include "opencv2\opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv2\imgproc.hpp"

#include "App.xaml.h"

using namespace eigeneApp;//and other using namespaces

Page1::Page1() 
{
    InitializeComponent();  
}

//Buttons Start
void eigeneApp::Page1::toPage2Button_Click(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
    this->Dispatcher->RunAsync(Windows::UI::Core::CoreDispatcherPriority::Normal, ref new Windows::UI::Core::DispatchedHandler([this]() {
        this->Frame->Navigate(Windows::UI::Xaml::Interop::TypeName(Page2::typeid),bibitemElement);
    }));
}
// other Button-functions are also here, but not relevant
//Tasks and the NavigationEvents are handled here and the String Helpers
```

As far as I know the Bibliothek.h contains a Class (bibitem) with openCV related functions. It is not possible to post the Code of the Bibliothek.h. But I also tried to pass a cv::Mat between the pages, it didn't work.

I also tried to write a class that contains a static bibitem and tried to use them in Page1 and Page2 to get the content from Page1 to Page2. Here is the Code:

```
#pragma once

#include "Bibliothek.h"

//NavigationData.h
class NavigationData
    {
    public:
       static bibitem passingbibitem;
    };
```

And:

```
//NavigationData.cpp
#include "NavigationData.h"
#include "pch.h"

bibitem NavigationData::passingbibitem;
```

Afterwards I added a NavigationData Element to each of the Pages private section and tried to use them. The passingbibitem-functions were usable on the Page1, but as I arrive at Page2 the Data of the passingbibitem is empty. So my static stays the same thougt was some kind of wrong...

Are there any ways of passing non WinRT Classes and Variables between Pages? And can someone please give me an example of how to do that?

> I forgot a function which is setting the bibitem-data to default
>   values in my OnNavigatingFrom-Handler. Now it seems to work with the
>   static Item in a seperate class. But if someone knows any other way of
>   passing the Data, feel free to post it here

Comment: C++/CX is a strict superset of C++. Just pass your objects around like you would pass around any other C++ object. If you want to get really fancy, wrap them up in a `ref class` and get resource management for free. But without code, we cannot help.

Answer (score 0):

Types being passed to the navigation function need to be runtime types (derive from Platform::Object^), meaning they should be 'ref class' types. Your idea to create a wrapper type is correct, but the problem is that public fields/properties need to be expressible in WinRT, so they can't be C++ types.

The answer is that you can make a wrapper class, you just need to mark them as internal. I wouldn't make it static, because that would be the same across all instances of the wrapper type, just make it an instance variable:

```
//NavigationData.h
ref class NavigationData
{
    internal:
       bibitem passingbibitem;
};
```

Comment: Thank you for this idea, but if I try to write a header with "internal:"-specifier, it is giving me some errors. It seems like it is not possible to take the "internal:"-specifier in a normal c++ class. With a "ref class" its possible to use the "internal:"-specifier. But when I try to, Visual Studio throws 3 Compiler errors: C2664, C3073 and C3076. One is about converting between my class and object is not possible, the others are about the copy-constructor and something about a instance of a ref type can't be bedded in a system related type...

Comment: Sorry - the NavigationData shim class should be a 'ref' class. Can you provide a more complete example showing the compiler errors and the full compiler output? I can't deduce what your problem would be based just on the error codes.